# Actions.popTo(tabBarKey) breaks app. - React Native Router Flux

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

In my current app the user fills out a form that is made up of different Scenes and once the last Scene of the form is reached and the submit was successful, I want to "popTo" back to the initial Scene. However, this initial scene is within a `<Tabs>` tag and I think it is the reason why its breaking my app.

This is my Router.js:

```
const RouterComponent = () => {
return (
<Router>
  <Scene key="root">
    <Scene key="spinnerBucket">
      <Scene
        key="spinner"
        component={SpinnerComponent}
        initial
        hideNavBar
        panHandlers={null}
      />
    </Scene>

    <Scene key="authBucket">
      <Scene
        key="login"
        component={LoginComponent}
        initial
        hideNavBar
        panHandlers={null}
      />
    </Scene>


    <Tabs
      lazy
      headerMode="none"
      key="tabBar"
      navBar={NavigationComponent}
      tabBarPosition={'bottom'}
     >
      <Scene
        key="home"
        initial
        component={HomeComponent}
        panHandlers={null}
        />

      <Scene
        key="profile"
        component={ProfileComponent}
        panHandlers={null}
        />

      <Scene
        key="activeJobs"
        component={ActiveJobsComponent}
        panHandlers={null}
        />

      <Scene
        key="favorites"
        component={FavoritesComponent}
        panHandlers={null}
        />

      <Scene
        key="inbox"
        component={InboxComponent}
        panHandlers={null}
        />
    </Tabs>


    <Scene
      key="displayOffer"
      hideNavBar
      component={DisplayOffersComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key="selectJob"
      hideNavBar
      component={SelectJobComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key="createJob"
      hideNavBar
      component={JobScheduleComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key="define_title"
      hideNavBar
      component={DefineTitleComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key="requirements"
      hideNavBar
      component={RequirementsComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key="quantity_question"
      hideNavBar
      component={QuantityQuestionComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key="add_comments"
      hideNavBar
      component={AddCommentsComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key="multiple_choice"
      hideNavBar
      component={MultipleChoiceComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key="infoMissing"
      hideNavBar
      component={InfoMissingComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key="user_description"
      hideNavBar
      component={JobDetailsComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key="jobDetailsPhotos"
      hideNavBar
      component={JobTagsAndPhotosComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key="googlePlaces"
      hideNavBar
      component={GooglePlacesComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key="chat"
      hideNavBar
      component={ChatComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />

    <Scene
      key="publicProfile"
      hideNavBar
      component={PublicProfileComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />
  </Scene>
</Router>
);
};
```

Now the issue arises when I am in the

```
    <Scene
      key="jobDetailsPhotos"
      hideNavBar
      component={JobTagsAndPhotosComponent}
      panHandlers={null}
    />
```

and I call `Actions.popTo("tabBar");`. The app just freezes and breaks. My question is: Is the structure of my scenes the fault or is there a special way to popTo a Tab?

My goal is to go back to the `<Scene key="home"/>`.

Comment: Have you tried to pop to "home" directly ?

Comment: @TimH You mean `Actions.popTo('home');`? I have tried that and it also breaks the app because it is within the `Tabs` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use only 'leaf' scene keys for popTo.

Comment: Hey @aksonov, thanks for the answer. Could you elaborate a bit more? I still dont quiet understand... In my case, how would I then correctly navigate back to the Tab Bar while correctly unmounting the stack?

Comment: popTo implementation is quite straightforward right now - it does 'pop' until scene name will be the same as given. That is why only 'leaf' keys are supported (i.e. specific tab that exist in your stack). For your use case you probably need to use `replace`

Comment: `Actions.replace('home')` also navigates me to the Scene w the key `home`, however it does not unmount the other Views correctly. I also achieved this by simply doing `Actions.home()`.

Comment: I think there should be support for popping to parent as well. I just felt the need to pop to parent tabbar. Hope, we will see it in future versions. Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

`Actions.popTo` works fine, just use it like this:

```
Actions.popTo("sceneName");
```

Version:

```
"react": "16.0.0",
"react-native": "^0.51.0",
"react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.28",
```

Answer (score 0):

You cad add explicitly your scene to the stack by doing `Actions.theNameForYourScene` in the startup before the main scene, in order to be able to popTo it after. It's not recommended but it works.